# PHP project works locally perfect and on external host it doesn't

Tags: php, doctrine, xampp, web-hosting

I'm new with PHP and created a demo rest API so I can test my "in development" Android app to work with API's and Json

Te demo API works fine on my desktop with XAMPP but when I upload the project to my external hosting provider i constantly get errors. Some of them I fixed by myself but now I have error I can't get fixed.

Project information:
- Use MySQL Database
-- Tables are exported from desktop to external host
-- Database connection is updated with the external information
- Use doctrine as ORM
-- Works without any problem on my local setup

The error(s)

```
[18-Feb-2016 09:36:32 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: The target-entity DemoApi\src\child cannot be found in 'DemoApi\src\Alert#Child'. in /home/aaapi/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:740
Stack trace:
#0 /home/aaapi/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php(953): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::invalidTargetEntityClass('DemoApi\\src\\chi...', 'DemoApi\\src\\Ale...', 'Child')
#1 /home/aaapi/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(198): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->validateAssociations()
#2 /home/aaapi/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(177): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->validateRuntimeMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL)
#3 /home/aaapi/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(332): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoa in /home/aaapi/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 740
```

I'm sure that the files entity classes exist and are correct else it wouldn't work in XAMPP or are i'am wrong about that?

**------------- UPDATE -------------**

File permissions are 755 for all folders and 644 for all php files

Comment: check file permission?

Comment: The file permissions are 755 for folders and 644 for ALL php files, i think this is right, isn't it ?, i will update this in my question

Comment: yes file permission are good

Comment: change `\\\` to '\' in your code

Comment: I tought something like that but i don't use \\, only in my namespace declaration but there i need it becouse i need 1 \ to escape?? so \\ is correct there i think...  (edit the \\ in \ or / in there don't change the error)

Comment: It is case sensitive on *nix. Check your annotations. `Child` and `child` are different things.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution, i don't know why i didn't see this by my self....